# Arduino class initialization execution

Tags: c++, class, oop, arduino, lcd

I'm trying to code a simple firmware for an UNO Board capable of switching the content of a LCD (16x2) display when a button is pressed. I tried to write it using classes and headers so I could add more buttons to the code more easily. The problem is that my class intialization method isn't working outside a `while(1)` loop as shown below.

This doesn't work at all:

**main.ino**

```
#include "button.h"

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

//Buttons PORTX register
#define buttonPortx PORTD
//Buttons DDRx register
#define buttonDdrx DDRD
//Buttons PINx register
#define buttonPinx PIND
//Buttons pins definition
#define B0 PD2
#define B1 PD3
#define B2 PD4
#define B3 PD5

//LCD pins definition
#define RS A5
#define EN A4
#define D4 A3
#define D5 A2
#define D6 A1
#define D7 A0

LiquidCrystal lcd(RS, EN, D4, D5, D6, D7);
Button button1 = Button();

int main()
{
  buttonDdrx = (0 << B0) | (0 << B1) | (0 << B2) | (0 << B3);
  buttonPortx = (1 << B0) | (1 << B1) | (1 << B2) | (1 << B3);

  //My initialization method:
  button1.Initialize(buttonPinx, B0);

  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(5,0);
  lcd.print("Hello!");

  while (1)
  {
    if (button1.IsReleased())
    {
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(4,0);
      lcd.print("Pressed!");
      while (1);
    }
    _delay_ms(50);
  }
}
```

But this one works very well:

**main.ino**

```
#include "button.h"

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

//Buttons PORTX register
#define buttonPortx PORTD
//Buttons DDRx register
#define buttonDdrx DDRD
//Buttons PINx register
#define buttonPinx PIND
//Buttons pins definition
#define B0 PD2
#define B1 PD3
#define B2 PD4
#define B3 PD5

//LCD pins definition
#define RS A5
#define EN A4
#define D4 A3
#define D5 A2
#define D6 A1
#define D7 A0

LiquidCrystal lcd(RS, EN, D4, D5, D6, D7);
Button button1 = Button();

int main()
{
  buttonDdrx = (0 << B0) | (0 << B1) | (0 << B2) | (0 << B3);
  buttonPortx = (1 << B0) | (1 << B1) | (1 << B2) | (1 << B3);

  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(5,0);
  lcd.print("Hello!");

  while (1)
  {
    //My initialization method:
    button1.Initialize(buttonPinx, B0);
    if (button1.IsReleased())
    {
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(4,0);
      lcd.print("Pressed!");
      while (1);
    }
    _delay_ms(50);
  }
}
```

And my header/cpp files:

**button.h**

```
#ifndef Button_h
#define Button_h

class Button
{
  public:
    Button();
    void Initialize(int port, int pin);
    bool IsReleased();
  private:
    bool pressed = false;
    int _port;
    int _pin;
};

#endif
```

**button.cpp**

```
#include "button.h"

Button::Button()
{

}

void Button::Initialize(int port, int pin)
{
  _port = port;
  _pin = pin;
}

bool Button::IsReleased()
{
  if (!(_port & (1 << _pin)) && (pressed == false))
  {
    pressed = true;
  }
  if ((_port & (1 << _pin)) && (pressed == true))
  {
    pressed = false;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

I was using C++ class constructors with parameters to set `_port` and `_pin` values, but afer taking a look at [this](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=45794.0) forum thread I created the `Initialize(int port, int pin)` method but still couldn't solve the issue.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your _`port` variable is simple int. It won't get anything from the real `PINx` register. It should be at least volatile pointer to byte (and dereferenced).

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) ! I will modify my code. But I still doesn't understand why it works when the `Initialize` method is in a loop. Could you help me with that? I tried to print the value of the int variable `_port` and it seems legit, according to the `PINx` register state. What makes everything even more stranger to me.

Comment: @KawaungaXDG when you call Initialize, you'll read content of corresponding PINx register and you store it as _port. But it's just a copy. It's not the actual PINx state, it's state of PINx when the Initialize was called.

Comment: Oh now it makes sense! Thanks for the explanation! It really helped!